# Como hacer que FileDialog solo me acepte un tipo de archivo en concreto

Tags: java

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación que maneja archivos planos, la cual permitira leer, y escribir un archivo.txt mediante el mencionado programa.

Para ello he implementado un FileDialog, el cual me permite escojer un documento ya existente para poder posteriormente leer y adicionar contenido en él.

Mis inquietudes son 2:

¿Como puedo hacer que el FileDialog solo pueda aceptar y abrir archivos que unicamente tengan la extención .txt?

¿Como puedo hacer que la barrita del FileDilog "Files of type" tenga siempre selecionado la extención ".txt"?

[image]

Este es FileDialog que genero para selecionar el archivo ".txt", pero que no se encuentra establecido por default en "Files of type", ademas de admitirme cualquier otro tipo de archivo

este es mi codigo(almenos la parte del FileDialog):

```
 private void SELECTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    FileDialog dialogoArchivo;
    dialogoArchivo = new FileDialog(this, "Lista de Archivos desde Frame",FileDialog.LOAD);
    dialogoArchivo.setVisible(true);
    if(dialogoArchivo.getFile()!=null)
    { /* Validar que se haya Seleccionado un Archivo*/

       directorio = dialogoArchivo.getDirectory();
       nombreArchivo =dialogoArchivo.getFile(); 
       ruta= directorio + nombreArchivo;
       lblname.setText("NAME FILE:"+nombreArchivo);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("No Seleccionó Archivo");

}
```

Trato de explicar la problematica de la mejor manera que puedo.
Sí es necesario el codigó completo, editare la pregunta.
gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Usa el método `setFilenameFilter()` enviándole como parámetro un objeto que implemente la interface `FilenameFilter`.

```
dialogoArchivo.setFilenameFilter( new FilenameFilter(){
   @Override
   public boolean accept(File dir, String name){
      return name.endsWith(".txt");
   }
});
```

Comment: podrias darme un ejemplo mas detallado?